# Errors while trying to install nginx-extras on buster on an RPi 3 B+

Tags: raspbian-buster

I tried to install with following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nginx-extras
```

This was the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libhiredis0.14 libnginx-mod-http-cache-purge libnginx-mod-http-fancyindex libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter libnginx-mod-http-lua libnginx-mod-http-ndk
  libnginx-mod-http-perl libnginx-mod-http-uploadprogress libnginx-mod-nchan
Suggested packages:
  nginx-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nginx-full
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libhiredis0.14 libnginx-mod-http-cache-purge libnginx-mod-http-fancyindex libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter libnginx-mod-http-lua libnginx-mod-http-ndk
  libnginx-mod-http-perl libnginx-mod-http-uploadprogress libnginx-mod-nchan nginx-extras
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 1 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,491 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,890 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf libnginx-mod-http-cache-purge armhf 1.14.2-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf libnginx-mod-http-fancyindex armhf 1.14.2-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter armhf 1.14.2-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:4 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf libnginx-mod-http-ndk armhf 1.14.2-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:5 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf libnginx-mod-http-lua armhf 1.14.2-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:6 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf libnginx-mod-http-perl armhf 1.14.2-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:7 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf libnginx-mod-http-uploadprogress armhf 1.14.2-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:9 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf libnginx-mod-nchan armhf 1.14.2-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:10 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf nginx-extras armhf 1.14.2-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Get:8 http://raspbian.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libhiredis0.14 armhf 0.14.0-3 [28.9 kB]
Fetched 28.9 kB in 2s (18.1 kB/s)                         
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/nginx/libnginx-mod-http-cache-purge_1.14.2-2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/nginx/libnginx-mod-http-fancyindex_1.14.2-2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/nginx/libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter_1.14.2-2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/nginx/libnginx-mod-http-ndk_1.14.2-2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/nginx/libnginx-mod-http-lua_1.14.2-2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/nginx/libnginx-mod-http-perl_1.14.2-2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/nginx/libnginx-mod-http-uploadprogress_1.14.2-2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/nginx/libnginx-mod-nchan_1.14.2-2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/nginx/nginx-extras_1.14.2-2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I noticed that while the install is looking for this file:

http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/nginx/libnginx-mod-http-cache-purge_1.14.2-2_armhf.deb

this is what actually exists on the package server:

```
libnginx-mod-http-cache-purge_1.14.2-2+deb10u1_armhf.deb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem:

```
sudo apt update --fix-missing
```